# replace method produces unexpected results if replacement has $'

Tags: javascript

When replacement string has $' characters, replace method results with strange strings.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1jns2eo9/

```
var p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';

var regex = /dog/gi;

document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = p.replace(regex, '$');
/// The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy $. If the $ reacted, was it really lazy?
document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = p.replace(regex, "$'");
/// The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy . If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?. If the reacted, was it really lazy? reacted, was it really lazy?
```

Comment: "`$'` Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description

Comment: If you don't want that to happen, use backslashes `\$\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when using `replace`, the second parameter can use [special syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) to make the replacement dynamic. The `$'` pattern

> Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.

So, for example

```js
var str = "abcd";
var regex = /b/;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$'"))
```

You would get `acdcd` because **b** is replaced with the string that follows it: ab**cd**.

This can be more apparent if we use the `$'` pattern as part of another string replacement

```js
var str = "abcd";
var regex = /b/;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "(-replacement: $' :replacement-)"))
```

If you want to avoid that and insert a literal `$'`, you can use `$$` instead of a single `$` which is the pattern to use to insert a simple literal `$` character and thus avoids using other dynamic replacements:

```js
var str = "abcd";
var regex = /b/;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$$'"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the character with

```
replace(regex, "\$")
```

$ in replace target has a special meaning: Put matching group in string

Comment: This does nothing: `\$` will escape `$` *within the string literal*. So what you are actually passing as a second argument to `.replace` is a string with *content* of `$`. `"\$"` and `"$"` are equivalent, the produce the same string content.